# Excel-Range XML uses two rows for header

Tags: xml, vba, excel, dom

I use [this](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/vba-trick-of-the-week-range-to-recordset-without-making-connection/) function to get recordsets from `Range`-Objects without setting up ADO-connections.

```
Function GetRecordset(rng As Range) As Object    

    Dim xlXML As Object
    Dim rst As Object

    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set xlXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    xlXML.LoadXML rng.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)

    rst.Open xlXML

    Set GetRecordset = rst

End Function
```

I typically use **one** header row. I get the expected results if the data starts in `Row(1)`.

However, if there are 1+ `Rows` above the data, excel assumes i have **two** header-rows and concatenates them with a blank.

Therefore, my recordset uses Fieldnames like `![Underneath's your header, mate MyField]` instead of `![MyField]`.

More technically speaking, the problem is that `rng.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)` returns the concatenated two rows as header and I'm unable to set that to one row.

Interested to hear your thoughts!

**EDIT:** a workaround might be to replace leading blanks with something like

```
xlXML.LoadXML Replace(rng.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML), "rs:name="" ", "rs:name=""")
```

or an iterative

```
Replace XML, "rs:name=""Cell1 Cell", "rs:name=""Cell2")
```

for each datafield

Comment: Just leave the "extra" header row out of the `Range` you pass the function - i.e. define your range starting in `Row(2)`...

Comment: Thanks, but ofc I tested this before posting. `Range.Value` will extend it's range to get a value for `AttributeType rs:name="<<Header>>"` to up to two `Rows` upwards.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same issue. The only way around I've found so far is to just insert another row above the header row and then pass the required range after that.

When filtering I have to append an extra space at the beginning.
So

```
RS.Filter = "[field_header] = " & strSome_text
```

becomes

```
RS.Filter = "[ field_header] = " & strSome_text
```

as it appears Excel is appending it. I am trying `Trim`:

```
xlXML.LoadXML Trim(rngInputRange.value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML))
```

with no joy. A couple of my headers have spaces so using `Replace` makes things much more ugly.

Adding the extra row and appending the space to the beginning of the field name means that I can filter on field names with spaces as I could normally with the header row on row 1, so although a bit dirty, this is a good enough workaround for me for now.

Comment: Try `Debug.Print rngInputRange.value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)`. The XML code shows us why`Trim` won't work here. A more specific `Replace` will likely solve the problem, **if** the row above the header row is blank: `xlXML.LoadXML Replace(rngInputRange.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML), "rs:name="" ", "rs:name=""")`.
Technically, one could dynamically replace the `rs:name="Cell1 Cell2"` with `rs:name="Cell2"` regardless of Cell1's content